# Error while installing Salesforec Mobile sdk for IOS

Tags: mobile, sdk

Hii all,

I want to install salesforce mobile sdk in my mac machine.And I have found the way to install it from the link given below.
https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS
But while installing via ./install.sh I am getting an error as show below

> ```
> [exec] Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
> [exec]   "_ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions", referenced from:
> [exec]       anon in SalesforceHybridSDK(SalesforceHybridSDK)
> [exec]       anon in SalesforceHybridSDK(SalesforceHybridSDK)
> [exec]       anon in SalesforceHybridSDK(SalesforceHybridSDK)
> [exec]       anon in SalesforceHybridSDK(SalesforceHybridSDK)
> [exec]   "_ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion", referenced from:
> [exec]       anon in SalesforceHybridSDK(SalesforceHybridSDK)
> [exec] ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
> [exec] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> [exec] 
> [exec] 
> [exec] ** BUILD FAILED **
> [exec] 
> [exec] 
> [exec] The following build commands failed:
> [exec]    Ld sfdc_build/artifacts/Simulator/Applications/VFConnector.app/VFConnector >normal i386
> [exec] (1 failure)
> ```
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   /Users/qbadmin/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/hybrid/SampleApps/VFConnector/sfdc_build /build.xml:34: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /Users/qbadmin/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/hybrid/SampleApps/VFConnector/sfdc_build>>/build.xml:41: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /Users/qbadmin/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/shared/build.xml:125: exec returned: 65

What should I do for fixing this.Please help me if anyone could.

Answer (score 0):

It was because of earlier version of IOS and Xcode.It solved my issue when I updated both.

Thanks.